# does google-app-engine has "required_admin" method

Tags: python, google-app-engine, admin, require

```
@required_admin
def get(self):
```

I want to use this method to make user must be admin.

Comment: I don't normally say this, but you really ought to read the manual. I get the feeling that you look at StackOverflow as a means of avoiding reading the AppEngine documentation.

Comment: i always want the best answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard route is to use `login: admin` in your `app.yaml`, but here's a decorator:

```
def admin_required(handler_method):
  def check_admin(self, *args):
    if not users.is_current_user_admin():
      self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
      return
    else:
      handler_method(self, *args)
  return check_admin
```